# Can I treat two users as one in track changes (word 2013)?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, markup, change-tracking

Scenario: 
the same user has two PCs and works on the same Word document from two locations, "A" and "B". When he roams, he cannot store the document online. The document must travel on a USB stick. 
The work done in Location "A" with PC "A" is saved, then more work is done in location "B" with PC "B".

Problem:
even though both PCs show the same name and initials for the user, the PC recognizes the changes made on each PCs. Fors instance, if some of the wording entered with PC "A" is deleted with "B", Word will track the change. If the same happens again when  "A" is used afterwards, more changes will be tracked even though it just the same user's refinement on his work.
The result is a mess of colors and overlapping changes.

Aim: 
Is there any way to tell Word to really consolidate all changes made by the given user, so that the work done with "A" and "B" will be interchangeable?